# Font size during Kubuntu installarion

Tags: system-installation, fonts

How can I set the font size during Kubuntu installation?  The default size is much too small.

Note 1: I tried using "Try Kubuntu" rather than "Install Kubuntu". Indeed I did have the opportunity to run xrandr by going to Konsole via the Start icon in the lower left corner.  But no joy -- xrandr listed just one resolution, which was the maximum (3072x1920).  It rejected my attempt to set it to 900x600. Maximizing the screen just gave me a lot of whitespace. Perhaps my hardware (a Dell Inspiron 16) has something to do with this.

Note 2: I can see a way to solve the problem, but I don't have enough
knowledge to implement it. Create a program that change the resolution and then does another boot. I know that grub supports multiple stages of booting, but I don't see how to utilize that.

Comment: Open a live session, and change the resolution before installing. After installation, you can go to the highest resolution, and enable fractional scaling. However, fractional scaling often requires a reboot, so it may not help in a live session.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail how to do that? And from a live session, how would you boot up the Kubuntu installer in a way that preserves the resolution prior to the boot?

Comment: Which version of Kubuntu are you trying to install? (You can also specify the name of the iso file.)

Comment: Please look at the revised description of the problem.

Comment: @PaulA. At least with Kubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, it is possible to modify the font according to the second method in my answer. Please tell me if you have another version of Kubuntu where it does not work, and I will try to find a way to do it there too.

Answer (score 0):

I tested with Kubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (and I think it works with all Kubuntu 20.04.x LTS iso files).

### Quick and dirty method

- Boot a live session 'Try Kubuntu' (do *not* select install here)
- Start the installer from the icon on the desktop screen. Notice the size of the text. Make it full-screen in order to see the buttons in the bottom right corner also when the resolution is changed.
- Run **`xrandr`** in a terminal window ('Konsole') and watch the output. Select one of the listed screen resolutions, one that is low enough to make the text big enough in the installer.
- I selected

  ```
  xrandr -s 960x540
  ```

  but you might not have that resolution available, so select the best possible resolution. I think `800x600` is the lowest possible, that still works with the installer, but if you have a wide screen, there are probably better alternatives (for example the one I selected).
- Shift the focus to the installer window.
- Go ahead installing and enjoy the improved size of the text.

---

### Real modification of the font size

In computers, where you cannot select different resolutions, you can instead tweak the font size: Select

- Menu - System Settings - Fonts

  - Click the button Select All Fonts

    - OK and Apply

[image]

- Now most fonts, also in the installer's windows are bigger, and you can enjoy installing. Please notice that you need *not* do another boot. Click the icon for the installer on the desktop and run it ...

---

This method can also be applied in the installed system.